# Avoiding repetition when testing for empty fields in an if statement

Tags: matlab

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid repeating myself in the code below:

```
if (isfield(A,'test') && isempty(A.test)) || ~isfield(A,'test')
    statement1
else
    statement2
end
```

alternatively, this is equivalent to:

```
if isfield(A,'test')
    if isempty(A.test)
        statement1
    else
        statement2
else
    statement1
end
```

In the first example, I've repeated the `isfield` condition and in the second `statement1` is repeated. Is there a neat way to do this without repetition?

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
if isfield(A,'test') && ~isempty(A.test)
    statement2
else
    statement1
end
```

is enough.

Because using the operator [**`&&`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) the statement `isempty(A.test)` is just tested if `isfield(A,'test')` is true, otherwise it is skipped anyway.

> `expr1 && expr2` represents a logical AND operation that employs
>   short-circuiting behavior. With short-circuiting, the second operand
>   `expr2` is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the
>   first operand `expr1`. For example, if `expr1 = 0`, then the following
>   statement evaluates to false, regardless of the value of expr2.

---

Testing:

```
A = struct        % Case1
%A.test = 5       % Case2
%A = 5            % Case3

if isfield(A,'test')
    if isempty(A.test)
        disp(1)
    else
        disp(2)
    end
else
    disp(1)
end


if isfield(A,'test') && ~isempty(A.test)
    disp(2)
else
    disp(1)
end
```

For all 3 testing cases the results are the same.

Comment: I don't think your code does the correct thing - in the case where `isfield(A,'test')` is false, I want statement1 to be executed, but this executes statement2.

Comment: have a look at my edit. Play around a little with `~` - if it's still not working.

Comment: ... the downvote is maybe a little harsh for a typo.

Comment: That's perfect. This had been slowly causing my brain to melt.

Answer (score 1):

I think either

```
if ~isfield(A,'test') || isempty(A.test))
    statement1
else
    statement2
end
```

or

```
if isfield(A,'test') && isempty(A.test)
    statement2
else
    statement1
end
```

will do what you need.

MATLAB's `||` and `&&` operators short-circuit, so if the first operands evaluate to true (in the first case) or false (in the second case), the second operand is not evaluated and won't cause an error.

Comment: I think the second example is missing `~` in front of the `isempty` condition, but thanks for the equivalent `||` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's any other way, other than storing the condition in a boolean variable and passing it on, like this -

```
cond1 = isfield(A,'test');
if (cond1 && isempty(A.test) || ~cond1)
    statement1
else
    statement2
end
```

Though I must add, I would rather prefer the IF-ELSE style that you have adopted in your second approach. The case when 'test' field doesn't exist for A, it would throw error if you do only **isempty(A.test)**, but with the double checking of that alongwith **isfield(A,'test')**, I think MATLAB ignores the error.